# Django Error: cannot import name autodiscover_modules

Tags: python, django

I meet this error when I deploy my Django project on another VPS. The same codes can run successfully on my Macbook and a staging VPS.

My website based on Django 1.4.20, and import some third python library and Django apps, for example redis-py, requests, django-import-export, django-kronos, django-cors-headers. I install these by pip install etc

I'm really confused how these happen. Maybe it's a library dependency problem, but I can't find detail error log or stacks. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a `requirements.txt` with your webapp. Then do `pip install -r requirements.txt` when you deploy.

If you did not make such a file, you can create one later by running `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. But beware that there might be some packages there that are not needed, if you installed other stuff on the side, so be prepared to manually screen the file.

If you work with multiple webapps you may also need to containerize your requirements ([here's why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)). Two options: [Docker](https://www.docker.com) or [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). If you don't know what Docker is and don't have some time on your hands I suggest you go with Virtualenv for now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works. pip freeze command is really cool.